# The doxygen-maven-plugin doesn't use my own doxygen config file

Tags: maven, pom.xml, doxygen, maven-plugin

I tried to use the doxygen-maven-plugin of [soebes](http://khmarbaise.github.io/doxygen-maven-plugin/) with my own doxygen configuration file. But the plugin just keep generating a default doxygen configuration and use that to call doxygen. Does any of you used this doxygen maven plugin successfully? And can you tell me what to do to fix this problem?

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>doxygen_tst</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>nar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <doxygen.configurationFile>Doxyfile</doxygen.configurationFile>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin> ... </plugin> <!-- nar plugin -->

        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>doxygen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
       <plugin> ... </plugin> <!-- nar plugin -->

       <plugin>
        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>doxygen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>doxygen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

The doxygen configuration file *Doxyfile* is next to the pom file.
I tried to run with the goal 'site' as well as the goal 'doxygen:report'. Although both options generates the doxygen output files, neither of these options uses my own *Doxyfile*.
I also tried to set the property **${doxygen.projectName}** and that works. I see the chosen project name on the generated index.html.

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I added '${project.basedir}/' to the property and now it works. So the whole property now is: <doxygen.configurationFile>${project.basedir}/Doxyfile</doxygen.configurationFile>

Comment: Why not filing in [an issue](https://github.com/khmarbaise/doxygen-maven-plugin/issues) ? Apart from that If you have defined the plugin version in pluginManagement you can omit in the usual build area as well as in the reporting are (Except for Maven 3.0.5 you will get a warning).

Comment: You're right about filing in an issue if I am sure that I configured it right. And because it is now working, I guess I made a mistake at some point. I will look into it again.
Thanks about the remark on the version tag.